# How to get value from the following object in php?

Tags: php

```
stdClass Object ( 
    ['age_from'] => 18 
    ['age_to'] => 25 
    ['people_in_household'] => 1 
    ['household_gender'] => 1 
)
```

My code

```
$data = HaveListing::where('id',$id)
            ->with('roomDetails') 
            ->with('user')
            ->with('currency')
            ->first(); 
$jsonString = $data->roomDetails->household; 
$obj =json_decode($jsonString); 
print_r($obj->age_from);
exit();
```

Output from var_dump($obj)

```
object(stdClass)#1016 (4) {
  ["'age_from'"]=>
  string(2) "18"
  ["'age_to'"]=>
  string(2) "25"
  ["'people_in_household'"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["'household_gender'"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: For example `echo $obj->age_from`

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: thanks for quick response . but it showing the error "Undefined property: stdClass::$age_from"

Comment: Well it would help if you show us the real code and not just a `print_r()` of an object

Comment: $data=HaveListing::where('id',$id)->with('roomDetails')
            ->with('user')->with('currency')->first();
        $jsonString=$data->roomDetails->household;
        $obj  =json_decode($jsonString);
        print_r($obj->age_from);exit();

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "Undefined property: stdClass::$age_from" @pr1nc3

Comment: Then either the json_decode failed or there is no property called `age_from` in that object

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($obj);` and then paste that into your question as well

Comment: Yea as I thought! You have single quotes as part of the property name _SOMEHOW_ Is that something you have accidentally added ?

Comment: i didn't added something. i stored the data using `json_encode` function.that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have single quotes as part of your property name, see

```
object(stdClass)#1016 (4) {
  ["'age_from'"]=> string(2) "18"
  ["'age_to'"]=> string(2) "25"
  ["'people_in_household'"]=> string(1) "1"
  ["'household_gender'"]=> string(1) "1"
}
```

You will have to use

```
echo $obj->{"'age_from'"};
```

to address these properties.

> I would however suggest you look at why the single quotes are part of the object property names, and fix it so they are not part of the property names!

Comment: Thanks a lot. i found the problem and fix it. the problem in input field name -where i put `household['age_from']` it should be `household[age_from]` . it's my mistake.

Comment: Great, a better solution definitely